# Golangのスライスについて教えて下さい。

Tags: go

Golangであるスライスz = []Hogeを持つ構造体Aがあります。

```
type A struct{
    z []Hoge
}
```

このaの特定要素をAのメソッドBで新たに生成したスライスcにコピーし、それを返します。

```
func (a *A) B()[]Hoge{
    c := make([]Hoge, 2)
    c[0] = a.z[0]
    c[1] = a.z[1]
    return c
}
```

そこでこのcの要素に新たな値を代入するとa.zの要素まで変化してしまいます。おそらく、cがzの参照を持っているのだと思いますが、これを防ぐにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。ちなみにメソッドの*AをAに変えてやってみましたができませんでした。

```
c[0].Huga = "piyo"
//a.z[0]の要素までpiyoになる
```

**追記**:
上の説明がわかりづらかったので、例を作りました。よろしくお願いします。
https://play.golang.org/p/8c6ca441_Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c[0] = a.z[0]` とした場合、`a.z[0].Huga`(`Buzz` 型構造体)のアドレスが `c[0].Huga` にセットされてしまいます(shallow copy)。ですので、`Huga`の実体(`Buzz` 型構造体のスライス)もコピーする様にします(deep copy)。

```golang
func (a *A) B() []Hoge {
    c := make([]Hoge, len(a.z))
    for i := 0; i < len(a.z); i++ {
        c[i].Huga = make([]Buzz, len(a.z[i].Huga))
        copy(c[i].Huga, a.z[i].Huga)
    }
    return c
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://play.golang.org/p/dHcl9LNUjc

全体のコードを見れていないので分かりませんが、文中から起こしたコードだと `a.z[0]` は変わらない様に思います。

**追記**

リーズナブルにやるのであれば、一度 json 化してしまうのも方法です。

https://play.golang.org/p/XxAzFQIp7w

Comment: コードがわかりづらくてすみません。https://play.golang.org/p/8c6ca441_Z このような場合です。

Answer (score 0):

例のHoge, Buzz, Aが structである必要がない(他の要素を持たない)なら、例を

https://play.golang.org/p/L5eyeKZfCJ

のように書き換えると理解しやすいと思います。
以下のコードでどうでしょう。

https://play.golang.org/p/tve2IHjGG_